# Transforming a list in another list

Tags: java, list

i have a list of java bean, bean name is "bean_A"
and at run-time,  record entry in list is like

[record in list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu6Gb.jpg)

beanA properties are

```
class beanA
    {
        public String employename;
        public String employeBranch;
        public String designation;
        public Date absentDate;
    }
```

i want to transform it into another bean list with name bean_B
so the employee related information will not repeat in list

properties of bean_B

```
class bean_B
{
    public String employename;
    public String employeBranch;
    public String designation;
    public List<Date> absentDates;
}
```

so that record entry will be like
[bean_B record entry after transforming list bean_A will be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDDbi.jpg)

Comment: And the question is ? What have you tried so far ? Do you have some code to show us ?

Comment: In the images, `bean_B` List doesn't contain any item from `bean_A` List!!! So how come it's transformed!!

Answer (score 2):

Use a Map with name+branch+designation as key and List of dates as Values, Iterate on keys and fill up the table.

Comment: Adding link for Map interface for reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: @btreport Bro if possible share a code example or helpful link thanks